# Triple-Boot with GRUB on ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I installed the ubuntu first, then windows. Windows did overwrite on the GRUB, so i recovered GRUB and now I am able to dual-boot. My question is, if iI install Manjaro now, on a different partition, will i have to do the recovering process again?

Answer (score 0):

No you won't.

You have a working GRUB environment at the moment and Manjara also uses GRUB. This shouldn't give any problems.

Make sure that you check the right options on the Manjaro installation and create a FULL SYSTEM IMAGE so you can always jump back if something went wrong.

Hope this helps.